# IIS not using available memory?

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, iis-6, memory

Recently launched an ASP.NET site running on a single 32-bit WS2003 box (SQL on a separate server). The server has 4GB intalled, 3GB available. According to task manager, the w3wp.exe process is only using between 200-600MB. The site has tens of thousands of pages and makes heavy use of page output caching, so I would expect it to use a lot more of the available memory.

The app pool isn't set to throttle memory usage. Is there anything else that might be limiting the amount of memory that IIS takes?

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be anything else besides the app pool that throttles that. Are you seeing any problems, or are you just baselining the system and want to make sure you understand everything?

Comment: No, no problems - just seems strange, and makes me think that something could be preventing it from using the available memory.

Answer (score 0):

The site may host a lot of pages, but what about the load? If there are only a couple hundred http requests coming in per hour, I wouldn't expect the server to use up all available memory.

Also echoing mfinni's comment, are you having any problems or just trying to understand your server?

Comment: The site typically handles between 10K and 15K requests per hour.